# How to convert .vb to project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I made an application in Visual Basic 2008 Express but, when I saved it, I used by mistake the option "save as" and it created 3 files:

1. practica 1.resx
2. practica 1.Designer.vb
3. practica 1.vb

Now I can't open it as a project.

Is there any way to convert these files into my original project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you didn't save the project at all, only the individual files for the `practica 1` module.

Create a new project and import these files.

Comment: but how? And would that restore everything?

Comment: @ebelendez: What do you mean how? Create your project, add the files. These options are prominent in the Visual Studio menus. `Would that restore everything` I said no. Unless your computer is psychic. You deleted "everything" (by failing to save it), so it is gone. You must recreate it. But that's just the project file, which is not too important, right?